# Can Facebook visit my website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I hope I did it right by posting this question here. If not, please, let me know it and I will repost it ASAP.

The situation is: I have a single PHP page that records an IP address of every visitor and mails then to me (for corporate reasons, no spying purposes). A colleague I gave this link supposed to share it on Facebook via a private message to the third person.

Exactly after that I received an email with the visitor IP address. Searching it in Whois (because I did not find it in our corporate office IP list) returned me that this IP belongs to Facebook.

Is it possible that FB surfs for every webpage being sent in a private message (i.e. for preview ability), or this link is being visited by a FB user?

I am sorry again if I posted this question in a wrong website.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post a link on Facebook, Facebook automatically scrapes that page to look for a description and image to include with the link. It's likely that the server request that Facebook made to scrape your page is what sent the link to you.