# Add specific image and title to Facebook sharing link

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my shopping site project, I am trying to share the current link (which is product details page) on Facebook using the following url which is working fine:

```
<?php
    $shareUrl = urlencode($product_url);
?>
<a class="share-button-link" href="<?php echo "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" .$shareUrl; ?>">
   Facebook
</a>
```

The above one is working fine but the title and image of the current sharing link on FB is coming different. I mean the image is present on the current url but I want to show some other image.

Now, the current url has many images and I think, Facebook is selecting a random image from the collection of images and title is based on something else (*not sure*).

My question is: **How to add a specific image and title to the sharing link?**

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19388031/1577396) but doesn't work for me.

```
<?php 
    $product_url=$ _product->getProductUrl(); 
    $shareUrl = urlencode("http://www.example.com/product-a");     
    $shareTitle = urlencode($_product->getName()); 
    $shareImage = urlencode("http://i.imgur.com/59oQPGZ.jpg"); 
?> 
<a class="share-button-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $shareTitle; ?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $shareUrl; ?>&amp;p[summary]=nothing+but+you&amp;p[image]=<?php echo $shareImage; ?>">
    Facebook
</a>
```

I can't use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/1577396):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/ogp.jpg" />
```

Because the images will change for every product page. (I need change the image dynamically, which is not possible in this case)

Comment: _Why_ can’t you use the meta elements? If your page is generated dynamically, then where is the problem in outputting the meta info dynamically as well? (Anyway, you will _have to_ use those if you want to use the share dialog, because as of now that _only_ takes the data it displays from the OG meta info of the URL that is shared. If you don’t want that, you could use the Feed dialog instead, that still allows to set this parameters dynamically [for now].)

Comment: Do you have specific url for each content? You can do that with OG tags. If you can give further detail, I can help

Comment: As CBroe mentioned it, You can use `Feed` dialog

Comment: @CBroe sorry, I didn't get you.. please give a small example whenever you have time. I have solution in my hand, which I am showing in my post but don't know how to do this dynamically.. btw.. the code is in phtml template files. there the image urls is changing for each product.

Comment: I don’t know _what_ you want an example for. If you are able to output an image URL in your page’s content area dynamically, then why aren’t you able to do the _same_ with the meta elements – _output them dynamically_ …?

Answer (score 0):

Output your PHP variables to the HTML meta tags.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $shareImage; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $shareTitle; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $shareDescription; ?>">
```

Comment: did this work for you? hopefully you can still remember