# Display image from link's website

Tags: jquery, django, hyperlink

How can I achieve this:

[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCT55Sfg_YzcnU1U28zdXRhMWM/edit?usp=sharing) (I don't have enough reputation to paste the image here :/ )

On Facebook & Google and many other websites, when your post includes a link, it displays an image from the website's images. This makes the posts look better.

I have no idea how to do it (I don't even know how to tag this question XD) . I'd appreciate any general directions about what to investigate. Is it something Jquery can do?, should I try find a library (I use django)?, Is it complex?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this][1] question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images

Comment: What you're looking for is **embedded or rich content**. Here are some useful apps on djangopackages: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/oembed/