# how to use angular 4 meta service to update open graph tags dynamically?

Tags: angular, facebook-opengraph, dynamically-generated, facebook-share, twitter-share

I used Angular 4 meta Service to update meta tags dynamically and updated meta tags for each is showing in inspect window of chrome dev tool but on debugging from open graph tool of facebook and google,they show me the meta tags of home page.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook crawlers does not seem to interpret javascript. (Dec 2017)

As you can see in this thread:
[Does Facebook crawler currently interpret javascript before parsing the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25420887/does-facebook-crawler-currently-interpret-javascript-before-parsing-the-dom)

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question of [Angular 4 - Update Meta tags dynamically for Facebook (Open graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45262719/angular-4-update-meta-tags-dynamically-for-facebook-open-graph/48096658?noredirect=1#comment83183467_48096658). See reposted answer there!