# Share image does not change in facebook

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4

In my `rails application` i put `social sharing icon of FB.`

When i click on FB icon then popup open. `Title and desc` is display correct which i want but `image` is not display proper. Popup take a different image from project which i not assigned.

I tried lots of time to change image but not success. I also remove image from project still its display in popup.

What is actual problem i can not found. `Fb cache issue` or something different.

Any one have a idea then please share it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a url has been shared, Facebook's crawler, which has a user agent of facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+https://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php), will access your page and cache the meta information. To force Facebook servers to clear the cache, use the Facebook Url Debugger / Linter Tool that they launched in June 2010 to refresh the cache and troubleshoot any meta tag issues on your page.

More detail: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Hope this help