# Why won't Facebook sharer.php provide a selection of images when multiple og:images have been scraped?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

So here is [**a page with multiple og:image elements**](http://www.destinationtips.com/destinations/10-hollywood-a-list-fairytale-wedding-epic-fails/2/):

```
<meta name="post-image" property="og:image" content="http://www.destinationtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/tiger-woods-elin-nordegren-1200x800.jpg">
<meta name="post-image" property="og:image" content="http://www.destinationtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Sandy_Lane-1200x797.jpg">
```

However, when I [**click the sharer.php link on the page, Facebook only offers the 1st image**](http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.destinationtips.com/destinations/10-hollywood-a-list-fairytale-wedding-epic-fails/2/).

I was under the impression that it should present 2 image options. I have re-scraped the URL many times and the [**Facebook Open Graph UI even hints that 2 images should be available**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.destinationtips.com/destinations/10-hollywood-a-list-fairytale-wedding-epic-fails/2/):

[image: FB sharer offering buttons for choosing images]

Can you clarify how to get multiple images in the sharer UI?

Answer (score 3):

Still unsure why the sharer UI for multiple images has gone, but Facebook have updated the debugger, which [no longer shows the multiple image selection buttons](http://s27.postimg.org/swhne75r7/f_VP1u.png). Now, even when multiple image meta is scraped, FB will pick only 1 ("Based on included and inferred properties"):

[image: FB Open Graph scrape debugger]

Answer (score -1):

It seems it works fine everywhere but in the sharer-preview. I tried to post it on my wall, and it showed the picker. It even shows the picker in the image you posted:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, but do you get the picker when sharing the page from the site itself? For example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ap1k8t6t07v0uy/Screenshot%202014-11-15%2013.17.19.png?dl=0