# Magento: Post URL on Facebook is not getting information

Tags: php, facebook, magento, url

When I am posting URL (http://www.knifeindia.com/outdoor-survival/khukris.html) on Facebook, it is unable to fetch information.

But when I change **khukris.html** into something else like (khukri.html or dagger-and-khukris.html), It fetch all information but still image thumb is not showing.

Checkout the difference in both the links here : http://s14.postimg.org/9yjafuakx/khukri.jpg

Can any one have a solution to post URL on Facebook without change category URL?

Comment: roshani please refer this link to know `how facebook sharer select images`.. it will help you out for the thumb... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images

Comment: Thanks! Facebook already cached my URL once. so it is unable to fetch new info from same URL. so I "fetch new scrap information" from "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/" tool for posting again same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that Facebook has cached your `khukris.html` at an older state.

You can use this tool to force Facebook to have it re-fetch your website.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

I just tried it for you and and it seems to be displaying the new information now.

[image: Forced re-fetch]

Comment: Glad to hear that @Roshni :) please take a moment to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Hi james! Do you have any proper solution to this problem B'coz I have so many links which are not working. I have to "fetch new scrap information" for every link is time taking and temporary solution. Kindly Help me out with this.

Comment: Hey there, it seems that's the only way to submit a request to fetch new scrap info. If you need to do this on a regular basis, maybe building an automated module with simple HTTP POST request using for e.g, NodeJS would be better.