# How do I let the user pick the image that is going to be shared on the share dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share

I'm having an issue with the Facebook Share Dialog: **I would like to be able to let users select the image they want to share from multiple `og:image` tags like the one showed in this answer:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/7623986/2644146

As you can see, there is a left and right arrow to let the user pick the image that he wants to select. However, I'm not able to do that. Right now my code looks like this.

My image `<meta>` tags are:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="image_1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image_2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image_3.jpg" />
```

I am invoking the Share Dialog with Javascript SDK:

```js
$j('.my-button').on('click', function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'http://myshareurl.com',
  }, function(response){});
});
```

The result is a share dialog with only one image selected (Facebook is selecting the second image by default). Why is Facebook not letting the user pick one of the three images? Was this ability to pick the image removed? And what are the criteria for Facebook to pick the image? For instance, `image_3.jpg` has a higher resolution than the other ones, so it supposedly should be picked by default.

Comment: Pretty sure that was removed, yes. If you provide multiple og:images now, Facebook will chose one automatically. (How they chose might depend on the device used to display the post.)