# Facebook share: multiple og:image meta tags, but no image picker tool

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get Facebook to show its image picker tool when a user shares a page that has multiple image choices.

Here's a typical page on the site:
**unionsquareevents [dot] com/catering/sourcing/**
(I guess I don't have enough rep points yet to post this as a link)

I have multiple og:image meta tags defined. The site runs on https, so I've also included og:image:secure_url meta tags. The images are all > 200px x 200px.

I've read this post, though it was written in 2011: 
[How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images-and-other-metadata-when-sharing-my-url/7623986#7623986) And many others that echo it, though none from recent months / years.

I've run it through Facebook's debugger. There are no errors, all the right meta tags are shown in the 'raw tags we found' section, and all the images are rendering in the og:image field of the '...we constructed the following Open Graph properties' section:

[screenshot 1 of FB debugger results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nugz.png)

[screenshot 2 of FB debugger results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Ddv.png)

The scraped source shows all the goods as well, plus the og:url tag using https.

I'm starting to wonder if this is just no longer available in 2015? I can't find anything anywhere on their docs site about the image picker.

Comment: The Share dialog shows a couple of images to chose from for me. How are you initiating the share? Is it happening on desktop or mobile, or both?

Comment: I'm initiating from desktop, in Chrome 46 for mac. It's n/a on mobile because they wanted the share tools hidden at that screen size.