# Facebook share: correct multiple "og:image" tags, but no image picker tool appears

Tags: php, html, facebook

I found a similar, but still unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33830980/facebook-share-multiple-ogimage-meta-tags-but-no-image-picker-tool). I seem to have exactly the same problem:

```
<HTML xmlns    = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og = "http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
      xmlns:fb = "https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<HEAD>

  <META charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <META property="fb:admins"      content=" .... ">
  <META property="fb:app_id"      content=" .... ">
  <META property="og:url"         content="myURL">
  <META property="og:title"       content=" .... ">
  <META property="og:description" content=" .... ">
  <META property="og:type"        content="article">

  <META property="og:image"       content="myImageURL1.jpg">
  <META property="og:image"       content="myImageURL2.jpg">
  <META property="og:image"       content="myImageURL3.jpg">

</HEAD>

...

</HTML>
```

When debugging my URL in the [Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), it yields correct raw tags (and also displays the correct thumbnails in the "Open Graph properties", but no image picker tool appears when shared.

Comment: And what is a point to ask similar question again?

Comment: That it had no answer yet?

Comment: Is there another way to sollecit an answer? (Sorry I'm a Dummy)

Comment: You can upvote the question to try to get more attention to it. Or, after having enough reputation, you can assign a bounty to it. Look http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty, http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation and http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: Give us a URL that demonstrates the issue, please. And try making `myImageURL3.jpg` an absolute URL with `http(s)://` etc.

Comment: If you copy-paste this url http://www.martin-fleischer.com/index.php?Mode=MediumSize&dbFolder=Gallery%28Si%2926 to FaceBook, it will display triangular arrows to select thumbnails, but this does not happen on the website itself if you hit the "share" button o the bottom of the page.

Comment: Facebook decides when to show a selection of images to the user. As long as you have embedded the images properly and the FB debug tool has nothing to complain, there isn’t anything more you can do from your end.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. FB debug tool in fact goes smoothly, so I think I cannot do anything about it. Your comment was helpful.