# Using Facebook Sharer to Share Multiple Images

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I am trying to enable multiple images on a page to be shared to Facebook, as described in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images-and-other-metadata-when-sharing-my-url). The post indicates that in order to share multiple images, you need to include multiple *og:image* tags. I followed these instructions, as you can see from [this page](https://senatorforaday.emkinstitute.org/senator/ePT4B0td/joe-levinger).

If you view the source for the page, you will see that I have included three *og:image* tags, one for each of the page's three images:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/stickers/ePT4B0td-sticker.jpg"/>
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/posters/ePT4B0td-poster.jpg"/>
     <meta property="og:image" content="http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/secondPosters/ePT4B0td-secondPoster.jpg"/>
```

Each image on the page has its own Facebook link. Since I had specified three *og:image* tags, I would have expected that no matter which link you click, you would get to choose one of the three images on the page. Instead, you have no choice; only the second of the three images is provided.

I figured that this might be a caching problem, so I used the *Facebook Sharing Debugger tool* to see what Facebook was seeing. The *Link Preview* shows just one image, and the *og:image* category lists just one image, which made me suspicious. When I clicked on the *Show All Raw Tags* link, though, I discovered that Facebook was indeed picking up all three of my *og:image* tags:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/stickers/ePT4B0td-sticker.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/posters/ePT4B0td-poster.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/secondPosters/ePT4B0td-secondPoster.jpg" />
```

I then clicked on the *Scrape via API* link at the bottom of the page, and this is what I got:

```js
{
  "url": "https://senatorforaday.emkinstitute.org/senator/ePT4B0td/joe-levinger",
  "type": "website",
  "title": "Senator Joe Levinger | Edward M Kennedy Institute for the United States Senate",
  "image": [
    {
      "url": "http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/stickers/ePT4B0td-sticker.jpg"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/posters/ePT4B0td-poster.jpg"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://5194985117e2603e50e4-519b9b8712d3704cfc44947e6bab98a6.r58.cf5.rackcdn.com/secondPosters/ePT4B0td-secondPoster.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Visit the EMK Institute",
  "site_name": "Edward M Kennedy Institute for the United States Senate",
  "updated_time": "2016-07-11T19:51:09+0000",
  "id": "1101245249919459"
}
```

As you can see, the *image* key consists of an array of the three images specified in my *og:image* tags, so it seems as if this should be working, but it's not.

Any ideas as to what I need to do to provide the user with the ability to select one image from among the three that are displayed on the page?

Comment: Hello Joe, I am trying to achieve same. Did you got any success?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images are 1600 x 630 which is at least 200 x 200, but does not match to 40:21 [recommended by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images).  Your 1600 wide image [should be 840 in height](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/).

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks for the explanation, Zack. I am not at liberty to change the aspect ratio of the images, so I think I will try another approach: embedding three _iframes_, one for each image, in the web page, with each _iframe_ containing the _og:image_ tag corresponding to that particular image. I presume that Facebook will crop each image to meet its specifications, but that will be acceptable. I'll let you know if my idea works.

Comment: Changing the image for each social media platform is typical.  Google+, LinkedIn, FaceBook, and Twitter (to name only a few) all have different requirements for images.

Comment: I tried the same with FB share dialog, But it always pick the first og:image. I couldn't see the image picker option in my popup. Is latest FB API's even allow image picker on share dialog?