# Facebook Pull Request to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Someone I am working for is having an issue where when she writes down the url of her site in a facebook post, it automatically pulls the first event she ever had from her wordpress site. Instead I want it to automatically attach the most recent event, rather than the first event. I think facebook is pulling the event from the wordpress calendar, but I am not sure how to fix it. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: How would Facebook know about any Wp calendar? If you share any URL, the Facebook scraper requests it and looks for Open Graph meta data, and if that is not present, it tries to figure out what the most relevant parts of the content are itself. (See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1138460/1427878 for details.) But those results are also cached – so the cache would have to be invalidated by triggering a re-scrape, if new info is supposed to show up.

Comment: But it would perhaps make rather more sense, if your client rather shared the URLs to individual events directly, instead of just the base URL.