# Set the Thumbnail Image for Facebook Share Buttons 2016?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, share

I'm attempting to set a custom thumbnail for when people share my website on Facebook. I followed this post here: [How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images-and-other-metadata-when-sharing-my-url)

It seems this info may be outdated because I am unable to get it to work. Can anyone advise if there has been a change and how to handle this now?

I currently have this in my head but It is not working:

```
<head>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Facebook simply had not refreshed my images yet. I found this tool to help with this process:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/