# how can I add a brand/logo to the facebook/twitter share images - og:image?

Tags: facebook, twitter, share

I've noticed that all the articles that The Guardian are publishing have a unique logo on the share image - og:image

[click here to see the example from The Guardian's post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX87P.jpg)

when I looked into the article's code, I didn't see the logo in the og:image URL
this is the og:image URL:

https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/f54a859ae94b8ca3998ab81bfee3e17e65ff21de/0_918_1702_1021/master/1702.jpg?w=1200&h=630&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=crop&bm=normal&ba=bottom%2Cleft&blend64=aHR0cHM6Ly91cGxvYWRzLmd1aW0uY28udWsvMjAxNi8wNS8yNS9vdmVybGF5LWxvZ28tMTIwMC05MF9vcHQucG5n&s=681c1f1e7d23bca848c895fc8ac0eeb5

my question: how do they add the branded logo to the og:image?

Comment: I see the logo...you can even move the logo around: https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/f54a859ae94b8ca3998ab81bfee3e17e65ff21de/0_918_1702_1021/master/1702.jpg?w=1200&h=630&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=crop&bm=normal&ba=top%2Cleft&blend64=aHR0cHM6Ly91cGxvYWRzLmd1aW0uY28udWsvMjAxNi8wNS8yNS9vdmVybGF5LWxvZ28tMTIwMC05MF9vcHQucG5n&s=681c1f1e7d23bca848c895fc8ac0eeb5

Comment: I think the answer to your question might be here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images-and-other-metadata-when-sharing-my-url