# How to show particular block or div from my entire page when i share with image and title on facebook

Tags: php, facebook, share-button

I found many codes but not working for me, I want to share a page but show particular block or div from my entire page when I share with image and title on Facebook.

when I share result should look like.
[image]

**my code**

```
<div class="content">

    <div id="mImageBox">

      <img id='my_image'  src='https://i.imgur.com/C8VWSZP.jpg' alt='tis is title' width="100%"
       onclick="fbs_click(this)"/>

      </div>

      <script>
         function fbs_click(TheImg) {
         u=TheImg.src;
         // t=document.title;
        t=TheImg.getAttribute('alt');
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;
      }
      </script>
 </div>
```

My code work perfect only for image share not working for image and Page URL. i want to share current page URL. it should be dynamic.

Comment: You can not specify any parameters besides the URL to share dynamically any more, all other data is taken from the Open Graph meta tags the URL returns. You will need an individual URL for each individual piece of content you want to share; sharing the same page under the same URL with different title/description/thumbnail is not possible.

Comment: ok, I updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images-and-other-metadata-when-sharing-my-url

Comment: Thanks, it help me lots