# I need to change the thumbnail that shows up when I post my webpage on Facebook

Tags: html, facebook, web, thumbnails

I need to change the thumbnail that shows up when I post my new webpage on Facebook and the information about it. It seems to have been saved in facebook's cache, but I culdn't find it.

My webpage is: www.bigotefilms.com

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6943607/1354137

Answer (score 4):

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.domain.co.uk/images/image.jpg">
```

Include that in your `<head>` it's what I used for my website.

Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6943607/1354137)