# Is there a Google Plus URL debugger like the one for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-plus-one

Do you know if there is a tool in Google Plus like the one on Facebook?

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes, here it is: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Comment: great link, but it doesn't show how a preview image would show on plus like facebook debugger does. any other hints?

Comment: this shows how your code needs to be formatted to be recognized: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ but neither this or the richsnippets tool refreshes the google cached like facebook debugger does.

Comment: This is not the same tool. This merely previews how the website will look on Google, not Google+.

Comment: @MohamedHussain I don't know of any LinkedIn URL debugger

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.