# Social Site Share URL Debugger For Google + and LinkedIn

Tags: html, google-plus, linkedin-api, social-networking

Is there any debugger available as in facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ to see what will be shared when we share a link in google+ and Linkedin to parse the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Google Plus URL debugger like the one for Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985398/is-there-a-google-plus-url-debugger-like-the-one-for-facebook)

Comment: requests for offsite resources are off topicon SO

Answer (score 1):

I know G+ only, not sure if LinkedIn supports/provides such feature.

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party but I hope it helps others. For linkedin you can use their [post inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/)