# enforce no facebook image preview when posting/sharing to wall

Tags: facebook, image

hi I found lot of useful answers how to force Facebook to post image when sharing link of my site on wall (f.e this one was really helpful [Facebook Post Link Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079599/facebook-post-link-image))

but I'm trying to achive opposite thing => "when I post to fb wall enforce facebook not to pull any image"

the only solution that I came up with is setting all my open graph meta tags and set image tag to be blank

```
<meta content='' property='og:description'>
<meta content='' property='og:image'>   
<meta content='MyTest app' property='og:site_name'>
<meta content='http://example.eu' property='og:url'>
<meta content='website' property='og:type'>
<meta content='10000123456789' property='fb:admins'>
<meta content='Movies and music' property='og:title'>
```

but in [facebook url linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) I'm getting

```
Object at URL 'http://example.eu/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.
```

so how to enforce facebook not to pull any img ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, in few minutes after posting this I discovered solution that won't cause linter error

set  the image og tag to your website (don't have to point to image)

```
 <meta content='http://example.eu/' property='og:image'>
```

but if anyone has any other solutions please shared them here