# Facebook not fetching all images?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I have wordpress blog with twentyeleven theme setup. I have facebook button and I beleive all facebook garph api codes are exist in head part. Now the problem is there are more than 4 images exist on the page, but facebook like button only fetching one image everytime. And trust me that is a huge problem for me.

Can someone help me fix the issue.
here is the link if you wanna take a look at: http://j.mp/GSfWKb

thanks

Answer (score 0):

While I can't confirm this is how Facebook approaches it, the og: meta tags only appear to work for actual like buttons, not Facebook sharing buttons (which are depreciated anyway).

According to this question you can try and put in a link tag and that may work for the share button you have. [Facebook Post Link Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079599/facebook-post-link-image)

Comment: that did not help. Facebook share still should fetch more than one image though. I cant figure out whats blocking it to get more than one image.

Comment: I don't have a definate list but things that can block it include, incorrect coding, no alt tags, your first image that is picked up actually has 2 "."'s before the jpg, which will probably cause the rest to fail. Image size being too large, etc.

Comment: all images has double quotation, title, and alt tag. This is wordpress default theme. How can it have incorrect coding ?

Comment: Your alt tags are empty, could possibly be the cause. 2nd, have you fixed the url for the first image. It has 2 dots ("..jpg") in the files name.

Comment: Alts tags are not empty anymore, and I have fixed the url still same problem occurs.