# How to get the website logo path from the link of the website

Tags: php

I have seen somewhere in the social website like **bluefoxx.com**, if you try to share the link of a website on the wall post like **champrep.com** or **google.com**, it displays the images for those websites may be the logos.

So can anyone please help me if i have to use same functionality in my php website how can i do that.

Thanks

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Comment: Fetch the website and search for a logo. Simple as that?!

Comment: please use the meta tag for this

Comment: thanks buddies but i have found the solution in this post                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711357/get-title-and-meta-tags-of-external-site

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079599/facebook-post-link-image

Answer (score 2):

It is either the file called `/favicon.ico` at the webserver or the file defined with `<link rel="icon">`:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# ASP.Net is simple ... you need to know the virtual path of that image ... bellow is a method that i used to save my barcode images that i ganerate into a web browser

```
public void GetPhoto(string filePath)
           {

               WebClient fileReader = new WebClient();
               fileReader.DownloadFile(filePath, Server.MapPath(string.Format("Image/someImage_{0}.jpg",txtBarCodeText.Text)));
               byte[] photo = null;


               string stream = Server.MapPath(string.Format("Image/someImage_{0}.jpg",txtBarCodeText.Text));
               TextBox1.Text = stream.ToString();

           }
```

filePath need to look like this... http://www.website.com/image.jpg
you can right click on web picture you want to get and look to properties to see it's path
Gook luck ;)