# Post a link and show thumbnails from that link - php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In some websites like **facebook**, when we post some **link** it show us **thumbnails** from **that website**, Like this in **Picture below:**

[image]

**How to do that?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079599/facebook-post-link-image)

Answer (score 0):

It's just a post/comment like any other. Only thing you need is info about that page. You can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for example to fetch page's data. Info you are looking for are in head of document in **meta** tags.

```
    <meta name="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta name="og:image" content="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6"/>
    <meta name="og:title" content="Post a link and show thumbails from that link - php" />
    <meta name="og:description" content="In some websites like facebook, when we post some link it show us thumbnails from that website, Like this in Picture below: How to do that?" />
```

Take those info and make your post/comment/whatever.

**EDIT:**
You don`t even need curl, you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014196/get-facebook-meta-tags-with-php)

Comment: Can you explain this code a bit ? If I am using <php echo $result['description']; ?> how can i retrieve this ?

Comment: Updated my answer, you have it detailed explained at link in my answer.

Comment: But how i am gona find the link in description ?

Comment: If you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12014561/2663825) you'll understand it better. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you need to fetch that URL and read the meta tags which will give you some information such as title, description etc. If you need to fetch the image weather read the image meta tag (exists if any) or read the first available image from the web page.